# How to write a GUI response into a txt file

Tags: java

Is there any way through which we can write the response from GUI(I was updating some data into a text box) into a file(In any format) using java code.

I am updating some values in GUI and in our java code I want to get all that data and store it into a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file and write to a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

Comment: Its related to DB not a simple java program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can write objects into a file.ser (serialized file).
Below is an example of how to write to a file using FOS.

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\object.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    Objec Obj ;
    oos.writeObject(Obj);
    oos.close();
```

Comment: can we update the same content into DB??
If Yes, could you please help me out to perform this task.

Comment: Dealing with databases is much more complex than just writing an Object into a file. But when you have large data to store , RDBMS is recommanded because it simplifies the work to be done.

So if you have small data to deal with , just  read and write into a file. If you're dealing with huge data to be stored than i suggest using RDBMS .

Comment: I can help you yes , but , give me an email address